# Spying on puppeteer calls

Tags: jasmine, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I'm building a web scraper that uses puppeteer.  I'd obviously like to ensure that I don't break things as I work the kinks out and so I'm writing some implementation tests.

How would I go about testing out the code below?  The issue is that newPage() is nested and I can't figure out how to create a spy for it.

Any ideas?  Should I structure the code differently to make it easier to test (from what I've read this a big no-no). Happy to hear your suggestions.

```
//myFile
myFn(){
let browser = puppeteer.launch()
let page = browser.newPage();
}



describe('searchAddress', () => {
            beforeEach(() => {
                browserSpy = spyOn(puppeteer,'launch')
                pageSpy = spyOn(puppeteer,'newPage') // <--- ????


            })
            it('should ensure the calls were made', async () => {
                await myFn()
                expect(sleepSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
                expect(pageSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();


            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case the `spyOn(puppeteer,'launch')` should return an object that contains a spy object for `newPage` call. I mean the followings:

```
describe('searchAddress', () => {
    let newPageSpy;
    let browserSpy;
    beforeEach(() => {
        // ARRANGE
        newPageSpy = jasmine.createSpy();
        let browserMock = { newPage: newPageSpy };
        browserSpy = spyOn(puppeteer, 'launch').and.returnValue(browserMock);  
    });
    it('should ensure the calls were made', async () => {
        // ACT
        await myFn();
        // ASSERT
        expect(newPageSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```